# How to Convert NSInteger or NSString to a binary (string) value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, binary

Anybody has some code in objective-c to convert a NSInteger or NSString to binary string?

example:

56 -> 111000

There are some code in stackoverflow that try do this, but it doesn´t work.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, `111000` is technically a negative number if you're using 2's complement.  `0111000` is positive (because of the leading 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which examples on SO didn't work for you, but [Adam Rosenfield's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655792/how-to-convert-nsinteger-to-a-binary-string-value/655846#655846) seems to work. I've updated it to remove a compiler warning:

```
// Original author Adam Rosenfield... SO Question 655792
NSInteger theNumber = 56;
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSInteger numberCopy = theNumber; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>= 1)
{
    // Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
    [str insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
}

NSLog(@"Binary version: %@", str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tooting my own horn a bit here...

I've written a math framework called `CHMath` that deals with arbitrarily large integers.  One of the things it does is allows the user to create a `CHNumber` from a string, and get its binary representation as a string.  For example:

```
CHNumber * t = [CHNumber numberWithString:@"56"];
NSString * binaryT = [t binaryStringValue];
NSLog(@"Binary value of %@: %@", t, binaryT);
```

Logs:

```
2009-12-15 10:36:10.595 otest-x86_64[21918:903] Binary value of 56: 0111000
```

The framework is freely available on [its Github repository](http://github.com/davedelong/CHMath).