# Obj C code's not working, isn't evaluating a method properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, binary

I'm trying to make an app to convert a decimal number into a binary number, but when I input the decimal number into a text field and have a button call the binaryConvert method, it continually returns 111111111111111111 (1 for every evaluation). Why is this??

```
- (NSString*)binaryConvert:(int)decNum {

    int i = 1;
    int value = 524288;
    NSString * binary = @".";

    while (i <= 19) {
        if ((decNum/value) >= 1) {
            binary = [binary stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
            decNum -= value;
        }   else {
            binary = [binary stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
        }
        value /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    return binary;
}

- (IBAction)convertToBinary:(id)sender {

    int decNum = (int)textField.text;
    if ([textField.text length] > 6) {
        answer.text = @"Too many numbers entered.";
    }   else {
        answer.text = [self binaryConvert:decNum];
    }
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

answer is a label.

Comment: For a smaller version of what you're doing, I'd suggest looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908845/how-to-convert-nsinteger-or-nsstring-to-a-binary-string-value

Comment: 1) What is `value = 524288` for? 2) you're just checking the result of  the integer division. You need to check the remainder of the division to decide if a digit is a 1 or a 0. 3) be sure you can do the algorithm by hand before you try to code it.

Comment: P.S. Objective C is evaluation the method properly. It's good practice to blame your code before blaming the compiler... you'll be right 99.99...% if the time if you do so.

Comment: @aleph_null: value = 524288 is because i want the limit to be 999,999 and 524288 is the highest binary value before reaching that limit. Also, if I checked the remainder, should I do this? if ((decNum%value) >= 1) then add a 1 to the string?

Comment: yes, the mod (%) operator will let you find remainders. however, i really don't see what you're trying to do with your code. Check out the link it Alex Taylor's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int decNum = (int)textField.text; // WRONG

Should be:

int decNum = [textField.text intValue];

// my previous wrong answer:

// decNum -= value should be done everytime; not only on if ((decNum/value) >= 1)

Comment: but then the next value would be negative because if !((decNum/value) >= 1), then that means value is bigger.

Comment: Ooops. My bad.  Your algorithm is correct.  The problem is the statment int decNum = (int)textField.text; it should be int decNum = [textField.text intValue]; int decNum = (int)textField.text simply puts the address of the string into decNum.