# Get the byte value of a string to replace it in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, byte

I want to be able to get a string (for example the letter @"A"), and I want to get what is the byte value (01000001) and change it to another byte value like (01000010) = B. Than convert it in a string again and replace the letter A for the letter B, in objective-c (xcode)

I'm I clear ? (maybe not...) Thanks for any help.

Vincent

Comment: A `char` is indistinguishable from a `byte` so what is your goal?

Comment: check this link....
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655792/how-to-convert-nsinteger-to-a-binary-string-value

Comment: My goal is to get the byte value (ex: 00100101) of a string like the letter @"A" and be able to change this byte value (UFC-8 format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `characterAtIndex` to get the character out of the NSString.  (It will return a `unichar`.)  It's a little tougher to go the other way, though.

It might be best to do `getCharacters:range:` to get the entire contents of the string, then `initWithCharacters:length:` to reconstruct the NSString.

Answer (score 0):

@"foo" is actually an NSString, take a look at the class documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Strings are immutable so you would need to use something like getCString to copy them to a char * buffer, change them and then create a new NSString using stringWithCString. Depending on the original encoding this may not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*I only have some background knowledge in Java, where I would tackle this problem as follows:*

***String*** has the methods ***length()*** and ***getCharAt(int index)***, which could be used in a ***for*** block to save each of the letters as a ***char***, for example in an array. ***char*** s can be casted into an ***int***:

> char a = 'h';
>
> int test = (int) a;

now all you have to do is to find or write a method ***changeIntegerToBinaryNumber()*** to get the binary number.

To get a letter from a binary number, the mentioned steps should just be reversed:
find / write a method ***changeBinaryToInterger()***, cast ***int*** to ***char***, optionally save the ***char*** in an array which again can be build together to a ***String***...