# How can I generate all possible strings with 16 characters limited to "a" and "b"?

Tags: java, string, random, char

I need to generate all possible strings with 16 characters. The characters can only be "a" or "b". How do I do that? I understand that there are 2^16 possibilities.

Here is the code that I'm trying to use:

```
public class Query5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Query5
        String s="";
        String [] hardCoded = {"16","13","3","14","11","9","4","6","15","12","2","10","8","5","1","7"};
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
                s=s.concat("a");
            else if (i==1)
                s=s.concat("b");

            for (int c=0; c<2; c++)
            {
                if (c==0)
                    s=s.concat("a");
                else if (c==1)
                    s=s.concat("b");

                for (int d=0; d<2; d++)
                {
                    if (d==0)
                        s=s.concat("a");
                    else if (d==1)
                        s=s.concat("b");

                    for (int e=0; e<2; e++)
                    {
                        if (e==0)
                            s=s.concat("a");
                        else if (e==1)
                            s=s.concat("b");

                        for (int f=0; f<2; f++)
                        {
                            if (f==0)
                                s=s.concat("a");
                            else if (f==1)
                                s=s.concat("b");

                            for (int g=0; g<2; g++)
                            {
                                if (g==0)
                                    s=s.concat("a");
                                else if (g==1)
                                    s=s.concat("b");

                                for (int h=0; h<2; h++)
                                {
                                    if (h==0)
                                        s=s.concat("a");
                                    else if (h==1)
                                        s=s.concat("b");

                                    for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
                                    {
                                        if (j==0)
                                            s=s.concat("a");
                                        else if (j==1)
                                            s=s.concat("b");

                                        for (int k=0; k<2; k++)
                                        {
                                            if (k==0)
                                                s=s.concat("a");
                                            else if (k==1)
                                                s=s.concat("b");

                                            for (int l=0; l<2; l++)
                                            {
                                                if (l==0)
                                                    s=s.concat("a");
                                                else if (l==1)
                                                    s=s.concat("b");

                                                for (int m=0; m<2; m++)
                                                {
                                                    if (m==0)
                                                        s=s.concat("a");
                                                    else if (m==1)
                                                        s=s.concat("b");

                                                    for (int z=0; z<2; z++)
                                                    {
                                                        if (z==0)
                                                            s=s.concat("a");
                                                        else if (z==1)
                                                            s=s.concat("b");

                                                        for (int o=0; o<2; o++)
                                                        {
                                                            if (o==0)
                                                                s=s.concat("a");
                                                            else if (o==1)
                                                                s=s.concat("b");

                                                            for (int p=0; p<2; p++)
                                                            {
                                                                if (p==0)
                                                                    s=s.concat("a");
                                                                else if (p==1)
                                                                    s=s.concat("b");

                                                                for (int q=0; q<2; q++)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (q==0)
                                                                        s=s.concat("a");
                                                                    else if (q==1)
                                                                        s=s.concat("b");

                                                                    for (int r=0; r<2; r++)
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (r==0)
                                                                            s=s.concat("a, ");
                                                                        else if (r==1)
                                                                            s=s.concat("b, ");
                                                                        System.out.println(s);
                                                                        System.out.println(" ");

                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this in?

Comment: Generate all 16-bit integers. Convert each to binary. Replace 0 with a, 1 with b.

Comment: Are you using a computer? Do you want to display all of these strings on the screen, or store them in the stack, or in a file? Do you know how to write simple computer programs? Can you solve this problem for 3 characters? 2? 1?

Comment: @Beta First time I've seen a commenter ask more questions than the actual poster...

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Yeah, it's usually not a good sign.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Java.

Comment: @Beta I know how to write simple computer programs. I was trying to generate them using 16 nested loops but I'm getting something else. I'm adding my code to the original question.

Comment: Does it work with 2 nested loops? (You should have tried that before attempting 16, but if not then try it now.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler method than N nested loops.

Start with a string of a's of the correct length. Start at one end of the string, say the left, and iterate through it.

When you find a 'b', change it to an 'a'.

When you find an 'a', change it to a 'b', print the string and go back to the beginning of the string.

When you reach the end of the string (without finding an 'a'), quit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what programming language you're using, so here is an example of script that you can convert to needed language. Objective-c has a string method for replacing characters in string with another, your language may require a custom method for this, just a simple loop.

---

Edit: you're using Java, you can use: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

for replacing 0's with a's abd 1's with b's

also convert int to binary string using `Integer.toBinaryString(i)` in Java

---

In the spirit of @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's comment.

```
array strings = [];
int i = 0;

while (i < 2^16) {

string s Integer.toBinaryString(i)

s = [s replaceOccourancesOf "0" with "a"];
s = [s replaceOccourancesOf "1" with "b"];

while (s.length < 16) {

s = s + "a";

}

strings = [strings, s];

i++;

}
```

^Note, this is not executable Java code.. It's just dummy script.

I don't program in Java... I do program Obj-c and made this script and it compiled fine and executed all possible values:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < (int)pow(2,16)) {

        NSString *s = binaryStringFromInteger(i);

        s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"a"];
        s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1" withString:@"b"];

        while (s.length < 16) {

            s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@a", s];

        }

        [strings addObject:s];

        i++;

    }

    NSLog(@"%@", strings);


}



    NSString * binaryStringFromInteger( int number ) {
    NSMutableString * string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    int spacing = pow( 2, 2 );
    int width = ( sizeof( number ) ) * spacing;
    int binaryDigit = 0;
    int integer = number;

    while( binaryDigit < width )
    {
        binaryDigit++;

        [string insertString:( (integer & 1) ? @"1" : @"0" )atIndex:0];

        if( binaryDigit % spacing == 0 && binaryDigit != width )
        {
            [string insertString:@"" atIndex:0];
        }

        integer = integer >> 1;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Borrowed Obj-c Binary conversion code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4393275/2057171